# how to create crystal report multi columns such as word

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, .net-4.5

i create report on crystal report and my width paper page larger than as my report and i want my report paging such as two columns on MS WORD my design report such as two image in below and i want create  report such as 3th image i use multi columns on detail tabs but not accepted result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In section expert, select the detail section and turn on the 'Format with Multiple Columns' checkbox.  This will make a new tab called Layout appear...